# Wolfram Language kernel not visible in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, jupyter

I want to use the Wolfram Language with Jupyter notebooks, and VSCode is the application of my choice. I did all the procedure to generated a WolframLanguage kernel for Jupyter.

If I launch the Jupyter notebook from terminal by running `jupyter notebook` in my terminal, a Jupyter notebook opens in my browser and it shows the Wolfram kernel. These are the kernels returned by terminal.
[image: I am also attaching the list of kernels shown by the terminal.]

They show up in the browser-version of Jupyter too.

[image: Browser Jupyter notebook shows these kernels]

Now I go to VS Code. I start a new Jupyter notebook by using the following command by using `shift+command+P`.

```
Create: New Jupyter Notebook
```

Now the kernel picker prompts me to choose kernels. Not only does it not have the WolframLanguage kernel, but it also shows completely different kernels from what were returned by the terminal. [image: Here is what's being shown.]

Please guide me on how do I make my WolframLanguage kernel appear in my VS Code.

Thanks!!!